# Subscript out of range in MSFlexgrid

Tags: vb6

I am using msflexgrid in VB6. How can I remove or resolve the following error:

> Subscript out of range.

```
With flxData(0)
  For i = 1 To .Rows - 1
    Do While cboselect <> .TextMatrix(i, 1)
      .RemoveItem (i)
    Loop
  Next i
End with
```

Comment: To indent code, just make sure to prefix each line with 4 blanks.

Comment: Once you remove a row, the subsequent rows will be renumbered, so when you get to the end of your for loop, Rows-1 won't exist any longer.  Try running your for loop 'backwards': `For i = .Rows - 1 to 1 Step -1`

Comment: Thank you for your response MarkL, i tried your suggestion but i still get the same error.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information, most helpful would be a complete recreation.  Can you add to your code to add a few items to the grid, then show how and when it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that the `Do While` loop inside of the `For` loop will cause the error to display - once a row doesn't have the desired `cboselect` value, it's going to call `RemoveItem` for that and all the remaining rows, until it's deleted all of them, then it'll display the message when it tries to delete a (now) non-existent row.

I'm guessing that you want to be removing just the rows that don't match the `cboselect` value, so that would call for an `If` statement.  You also do need to run the `For` loop backwards.  Try this:

```
With flxData(0)
  For i = .Rows - 1 to 1 Step -1
    If cboselect <> .TextMatrix(i, 1) Then
      .RemoveItem (i)
    End If
  Next i
End With
```